# Ninject interception WCF service

Tags: wcf, attributes, ninject, interception

I'm a newbie on the subject, so I'll try to make this as clear as I can...

I created a WcfModule, where I load the following package:

```
Bind<IDistributorService>().To<DistributorService>().InRequestScope().Intercept().With<ExceptionInterceptor>();
```

At first, I don't receive any error, but I put an InterceptAttribute on my function:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class HandleExceptionsAttribute : InterceptAttribute
{
    public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request)
    {
        return request.Kernel.Get<ExceptionInterceptor>();
    }
}

[HandleExceptions]
public virtual Result<List<DistributorDataContract>> GetDistributor(string id)
{
   //...code...
```

I get an error in this function: (first line in method)

```
private ServiceHost CreateNewServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses, WebHttpBehavior webBehavior, WebHttpBinding webHttpBinding)
{
  var host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
  //...
}
```

With the error:

> InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException was unhandled by user code
>   Can not instantiate proxy of class:
>   My.Namespace.DistributorService.
>   Could not find a parameterless constructor.

Anyone who knows what the problem could be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown by castle core dynamic proxy when it is instructed to create a "class proxy" which does not have a parameterless (default) constructor and no constructor-arguments are passed to castle (see [source](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/22e26f14a5a1ef90cca3fd9f9b7811ff693d2514/src/Castle.Core/DynamicProxy/ProxyGenerator.cs)).

My best guess is, that when you use ninject interception by attributes, ninject will instruct castle core to create a class-proxy, no matter whether your binding is `Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()` or `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()`.

It seems a bit strange, however, that ninject is not resolving and passing along all required constructor parameters.

What is the implementation of `DistributorService` and what's the implementation of the base class of the class containing `CreateNewServiceHost`?

Workaround: 
Of course, switching to the `Intercept().With<TInterceptor>()` syntax will probably also enable you to use interception (see http://codepyre.com/2010/03/using-ninject-extensions-interception-part-2-working-with-interceptors/)